# How can I change actual shell cd with nodejs

Tags: node.js, shell, command-line

I am creating a command line program to act as a shortcut for my environment. Commands like `$ cd $enterprise/products/<product>` are so common, that I like to compile into: `$ enterprise product`.

My problem is: I cannot change shell directory directly, like running `$ cd $enterprise/products/<product>` with `process.chdir`.

Using `console.log(process.cwd())` shows that the directory has changed, but not on shell, only on nodejs internal process(I think it's running on a own shell).

Typing `$ pwd` in shell shows that I still are on the same folder.

I was searching for a solution, like a shell script that interprets the output of a nodejs file, then `source` the output.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually bit trickier than it sounds.
You can't just change the working directory of the shell that is running the process, without making assumptions about which shell it is or the OS (I personally use applescript to spawn new terminal tabs).

What we can do, however, is spawn a new shell!

```
let child_process = require('child_process');
child_process.spawn(
  // With this variable we know we use the same shell as the one that started this process
  process.env.SHELL,
  {
    // Change the cwd
    cwd: `${process.cwd()}/products/${product_id}`,

    // This makes this process "take over" the terminal
    stdio: 'inherit',

    // If you want, you can also add more environment variables here, but you can also remove this line
    env: { ...process.env, extra_environment: 'some value' },
  },
);
```

When you run this, it seems like you `cd` into a directory, but actually you are still running inside nodejs!

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this; every child process has its own working directory inherited from the parent. In this case, your cd gets its working directory from its parent (your shell). A child process can't change the directory – or any other state – of the parent process.